# I asked the HR person if they could spend $39 on a dedicated Internet, and she spoke loudly to me "Not going to do that", why is that?

Tags: communication, human-resources

I talked to an HR person to resolve an issue, and it was a Fortune 500 company: Cisco.

During the Covid-19, almost everybody was working from home, but her Internet was not able to give a good video on Webex (similar to Zoom), and the audio sometimes was cutting off.

She said it is because it is one Internet connection, and is shared by her whole family.

I then suggested: since she had to talk to employees full time online during Covid-19, and it hurts productivity to not have a good Internet connection, can she request a $39 or $49 dedicated Internet for herself from HR.  $1.50 per day, but she works 8 hours a day, so it is really not much considering how it would help the communication between her and the employees.

I already heard she lives in some major city in Texas, working remotely, so it is not like she cannot get an Internet connection easily.

So at this point she raised her voice, saying, "I AM NOT going to do it. WE ARE NOT going to do it, OK?"

Why may that be? I thought companies, would almost always say, "At XYZ, we strive to always improve a coherent environment", or "At XYZ, we have the passion to produce a productive, good working environment for our employees". So why would they not do it and to the point of not saying anything but just giving an ultimatum that they are not going to do it?

Comment: Why do you feel you need assistance from SE on this topic?

Comment: Just because you live in a big city, does not mean you can get internet, just ask customers in NYC if they can get Verizon FIOS despite their neighbors in the next building having it.

Comment: @lycha, Maybe the HR person was simply having a bad day or a really tough day trying to resolve too many issues...   When people are having a bad day, if you simply let it go, you will feel better and have more time to enjoy your good day.   :-)

Comment: @lycha, I see nothing wrong with your suggestion. Perhaps, some people in this forum did not see that you wrote "I then suggested ... can she request a $39 or $49 dedicated Internet for herself." So, they mistakenly assumed that you asked the HR person to spend her own money on the internet. In reality, you suggested that the HR person "REQUEST" the company to pay for her internet. I guess that you just have a good intention of helping HR to improve the productivity.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 yes, again and again, when I had good intention in the USA, i get bashed. What kind of country has the USA become, I wonder

Answer (score 17):

> Why may that be?

Because you were infringing on her personal situation outside the context of the meeting.

She may have already tried and failed, there may be a policy in place she's unhappy with, she may just be having a bad day. Maybe she spoke loudly because you just told her the audio is unclear. But it's none of your business to suggest remedies that are not in your domain.

Comment: @lycha what do you want to achieve? You have no authority to do anything except make a formal complaint that the HR person could not communicate well enough for you. Whats the end goal?

Comment: @lycha Try to be mature about things.

Comment: @lycha No one is even vaguely suggesting you'r e criminal here.  Are you under the impression that the word "infringing" somehow implies illegal activity?  Perhaps because of "copyright infringement"?  You can infringe on things (such as someone's personal space) without breaking the law.

Comment: I suggested HR perhaps can spend $39 a month so that the important function of HR to employee communication can be improved. How is a suggestion an "infringement"?

Comment: You didn't do it in the right context.

Comment: "How is a suggestion an "infringement"?" - You can't know if they have already tried to get better internet.  It's also no your business if they can or cannot get better internet.  **You overstepped into the personal life of another employee.**

Comment: "infringing". sounds like such an accusation. And (1) I am making a suggestion for improvement of work / life only. (2) It is work related. It is not personal related.

Answer (score 7):

You requested that she spend HER money for the benefit of her EMPLOYER.  In general, the best answer to that isn’t “no”, it is “HELL NO”.  If she didn’t use any curse words, or accuse either you, your parents or both, of unspeakable acts, consider yourself handled with kindness.

Now, you might think that she could get reimbursed for this expense, but even if she could, that’s a separate issue and one you probably shouldn’t be raising with her, but instead either your boss or her’s.  If you think it is, it would be acceptable to confirm that it’s a reimbursable expense, and tell her so, but even then, she may not want it.  Increased internet service may change the expectations of her family in a way she doesn’t want to deal with.

Well, if you can’t tell her to spend her hard earned money for the employer’s benefit, what can you do?  You can tell your boss or hers that you had to communicate with her and had difficulty doing so due to her poor internet.

I’m sympathetic to her, as I have an internet connectivity problem as well while working from home, which I could probably get fixed for a few thousand dollars, but despite technically being able to afford it, I don’t consider it a good use of **my** money to fix an issue that impacts my work.  I haven’t asked (and have no intention of doing so) for my employer to pay for the upgrades to make it better.  While the cost to my employer to fix the issue would be trivial to them, I know that justifying the expense would be impossible, and it wouldn’t get pass accounting.

In both your case and mine, the inconvenience isn’t sufficient to rise to the level that it has to be addressed, so most likely any complaints will get sympathy, but no action.

Comment: You said, "You requested that she spend HER money for the benefit of her EMPLOYER. In general, the best answer to that isn’t “no”, it is “HELL NO”. If she didn’t use any curse words, or accuse either you, your parents or both, of unspeakable acts, consider yourself handled with kindness."  I suggested she can request the company to give her better Internet since she has to work at home, and you said some part of my family should be cursed. The hell to you.  I hope you and your family do indeed get fried in eternal hell

Comment: she is not just an average person in HR. She has been with the HR for 18 years, so she is part of the senior HR person and even is doing management. So this suggestion is properly raised to her, as she can discuss that with other HR top management

Comment: I didn’t say that.  You just quoted what I **did** say.  You were treated with kindness.

Comment: You said "You requested that she spend HER money for the benefit of her EMPLOYER. In general, the best answer to that isn’t “no”, it is “HELL NO”. If she didn’t use any curse words, or accuse either you, your parents or both, of unspeakable acts, consider yourself handled with kindness." I said in the question she can REQUEST it from her company, and you changed it to "Spend her money for the benefit of her company" and wrote an essay. So now if I didn't use curse words towards you, your parents, or both, I am treating you with kindness

Comment: You didn’t suggest that the company get her better internet, you said “can she request a $39 or $49 dedicated Internet for her”, which means can she ask her service provider to upgrade her account as it should only cost $39 or $49. As for treating **me** with kindness, hell is generally considered a mild curse word, so when you said “I hope you and your family do indeed get fried in eternal hell”, you stopped being kind to me.

Comment: No, if she simply gets it herself, it is "can she order the faster Internet". She "request" it means she request it from her company.

Comment: @StefanieGauss: unless you work for an ISP, you don’t request internet service from your employer. Regardless, if you think she should be reimbursed for faster service, suggest it to her boss.  She has a clear conflict of interest (and may already have asked and been turned down).

Comment: that's not true. An employee can request a better keyboard, or some ergonomic furniture. If her primary task is to talk to employees on the Internet 90% of the time, why can't she request a $39 per month dedicated Internet connection if she worked at home 100% of the time right now during Covid-19?

Answer (score 3):

The level of red tape that you'd have to cut through to get reimbursed for something like that may simply not be worth it. And if word got out that the company reimbursed one person for an internet connection how many other people might try to get similarly reimbursed? Should there be a formal establishment of criteria to determine who gets reimbursed for their internet connection and who doesn't? etc

Comment: how about for an HR person, who has to constantly talk to other employees all day long, can justify getting a $39 Internet for that purpose, for $39 per month, I am sure it is hardly 1% of her monthly salary. So spending 1% of cost, improving communication with employees by 70%, isn't it too obvious?